# Html form adding in hidden redirect button

Tags: html, asp.net-mvc, razor, umbraco

I'm using umbraco and letting it handle allowing my users to log in. I tried creating my own log in MVC but there is a lot of logic already built upon the old way. And I don't want to spend the time having to re-build it.

There for, I was wondering if there was anyway I could add in a hidden field that would allow the user to be redirected to my home page when the log in using the following form code:

```
@using (Html.BeginUmbracoForm<UmbLoginController>("HandleLogin"))
{
    <legend>Login</legend>

    @Html.ValidationSummary("loginModel", true)

    @Html.TextBoxFor(m => loginModel.Username, new { @class = "form-control", @placeholder = "Username" })
    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => loginModel.Username, "", new { @class = "alert-danger", @role = "alert" })
    <br />

    @Html.PasswordFor(m => loginModel.Password, new { @class = "form-control", @placeholder = "Password" })
    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => loginModel.Password, "", new { @class = "alert-danger", @role = "alert" })
    <br />

    <button class="btn btn-default">Login</button>

}
```

Comment: I can answer it for the more general case of form logins, but I don't know what kind of control that Umbraco gives you.  Usually, it's in the controller that you choose how and when to redirect.  Asp.NET automatically adds the ?ReturnURL={url encoded relative url} suffix, which is what the controller uses to redirect back to a specific page when they log in.  If the controller returns RedirectToAction("Index", "Home") they will always go to he home page.  Alternatively you can send them to their account page afterwards as well.

Comment: That makes a lot on sense. However, Umbracos log in functionality simply returns the user to the current page they are on. As I don't have access to the controller that runs this I have no way of doing it that way. I was really hoping there would be a way I could do this through some HTML code.

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to set the loginModel.RedirectUrl at the point where you're creating it, and then add the following to your form:

```
@Html.HiddenFor(m => loginModel.RedirectUrl)
```